# How can I change the style sheet of menu bar in qt?

Tags: c++, css, qt, titlebar, qmenubar

I want to change the styleSheet of my QmenuBar window. for QPushButton or any thing like this, there are several example like the following links {[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718722/how-to-style-qpushbuttons-checked-state-to-remove-grey-dots)} and {[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318538/qt-qpushbutton-stylesheet-hover)}. But I couldn't find any example for QmenuBar.

and I want to change the color of window background.

(I attach an image)

[image]

Comment: i think that is not menu bar, it is a title bar.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251399/how-to-change-the-titlebar-color-of-a-window-in-a-qt-qml-application